# Android Email sending from application to save in gmail calendar

Tags: java, android, email

Is there possibility of creating android application that sends a mail to gmail account in which the mail as the calendar event and stored in gmail account. When the event time reached, the notification mails is sent to the user through this gmail account mail server. the notifying  destination mail id can be of any type as yahoo, hotmail,etc.
Any help is appreciated and Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not send mail with android without giving user's permission, I mean you can open an intent that has the recipient mail address, subject and body, but user should press the send button. instead you can use java mail, and start a service that gets awake when the time reached, and sends mail to desired address. here you can know how to use java mail if you don't know, [click please.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html)